# How to create a chatbox that floats in the bottom right corner and is responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a chat box that floats in the bottom right corner of a website like this.
[image]

But my chatbox goes to the bottom end of the page which is not viewable.
This is my scss

```
.g_chat { 
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;

  &.collapsed { // window collapse
    height: auto;
    .g_chat_inner {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .g_chat_toggler { //  button to hide/show chat box
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  form { // form to submit message
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  #messages { // all messages here
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    .message {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      &:last-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I inspect my page, I see that the `<body>` tag is getting changed to

```
<body style="position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 0px;">
```

I don't know which plugin changes the body tag. Could that be the problem or am I missing something?

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: .g_chat{
  position: absolute;
  bottom : 0px;right:0px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might fix it..

```
.g_chat{
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh;
}
```

VH is viewport height.. so it will always be at the bottom of the page on any device!